# How to pass const pointer in parameter non-const

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, param

I have two pointers (const Vec* a and const Vec b)
in a given piece of code, I need to pass these two values​​, which are instantiated during the code, for a function that has no parameter (const Vec *) but only (Vec *).
How could I do this without moving the function definition, but if necessary, what procedure should I take?

```
//const Vec* from;
//const Vec* at;
Vec* viewVec; 
viewVec = Vec::sub( view->at, view->from);


//static Vec* sub(Vec*, Vec*);
Vec* Vec::sub(Vec* a, Vec* b) {
    return new Vec(a->x - b->x, a->y - b->y, a->z - b->z);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `const_cast` for this, e.g.

```
viewVec = Vec::sub(const_cast<Vec*>(view->at), const_cast<Vec*>(view->from));
```

Whether or not you should is another matter. If you really can't change the signature of the function (which is probably the easiest fix), you can always write a wrapper which contains the dodgy casting - that way, at least the caller doesn't need to do any casting itself:

```
Vec *Vec::sub(const Vec *a, const Vec *b) {
    return sub(const_cast<Vec*>(view->at), const_cast<Vec*>(view->from));
}
```

Comment: I am grateful for your help.
It really has been a great help to post questions here. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer is probably: "don't". If you need to use a `Vec *` instead of a `Vec const *`, then declare it that way to begin with.

If this is some third party function that promises not to modify it but for some reason has an aversion to `const`, then the `const_cast` solutions that other people listed is your only choice (other than to use a better third-party library).

If the `std::vector` that the pointer you have points to is actually not `const` (at its point of declaration), and you just happen to have a `std::vector const *` that refers to it, then it's 'safe' (but still generally unwise) to use `const_cast` on it. However, if you modify any variable that was originally declared as being `const`, then it is undefined behavior. For instance, the compiler may see that you are doing some expensive operation on a `std::vector const` multiple times, and it's free to cache certain parts of the result because it can assume that it's always dealing with the same thing, so if you change it, you may get incorrect (or even inconsistent) results.

Answer (score 1):

`const_cast<type>(value)` There ya go ;)

Answer (score 0):

As people have mentioned you could use `const_cast`. The reason you have to be careful doing this is that you might end up modifying something that shouldn't be modified. For exampl, if some object declares a pointer as `const` it is because it wants to ensure that this pointer cannot change. If you then `const_cast` the pointer and pass it to another function, the other function could make it point at something new, hence screwing with the original object which tried to protect it.

In particular, what if object A allocated some piece of memory which the const pointer points to. If you then pass the pointer to a function via `const_cast` and this function `delete`s the memory, or re-`alloc`s it, then the original piece of memory will exist undeleted.

Hope this helps.